# How to add facet in Tire (elasticsearch) to has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, lucene, elasticsearch, tire

I want to add facet to has_many association.

I am migrating from PostgreSQL fulltext search to elasticsearch.

Currently I have following SQL query to do search (PostgreSQL way):

```
rt = "#{Rule.table_name}"
Sentence.
  joins(:rules).joins(:regulations).joins(:speakers).
  where(:authority_name => params[:authority_name], :authority_detail_1 => params[:authority_detail_1]).
  where(:regulations => {:regulation_name => params[:regulation_name]}).
  where("#{rt}.description @@ #{Sentence.sanitize(words)} OR #{rt}.headline @@ #{Sentence.sanitize(words)}")
```

I looked at SO answer about similiar problem (HABTM association)

[Facet Troubles with Elasticsearch on Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895941/facet-troubles-with-elasticsearch-on-query)

and implemented code with similiar approach

-Sentence AR class

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other staff

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    indexes :id
    indexes :authority_name, :type => :string, :index => "not_analyzed"
    indexes :authority_detail_1, :type => :string, :index => "not_analyzed"
    indexes :authority_detail_2, :type => :string, :index => "not_analyzed"
    indexes :regulations, :type => :object, :properties => {
      :regulation_name => { :type => :string, :index => "not_analyzed" }
    }
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(:include => [:rules, :regulations, :speaker])
  end

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 5, load: true) do
      query do
        boolean do
          must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
          must { term :authority_name, params[:authority_name] } if params[:authority_name].present?
          must { term :authority_detail_1, params[:authority_detail_1] } if params[:authority_detail_1].present?
          must { term :authority_detail_2, params[:authority_detail_2] } if params[:authority_detail_2].present?

          must { terms 'regulations.regulation_name', params[:regulation_name] } if params[:regulation_name].present?
        end
      end
      facet 'authorities' do
        terms :authority_name
        terms :authority_detail_1
        terms :authority_detail_2
      end
      facet 'regulations' do
        terms 'regulations.regulation_name'
      end
      # raise to_curl
    end
  end

  # other staff

end # end of Class
```

But this code doesnt work.

After call to API I got an error:

```
Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed in SentencesController#search
```

{

```
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[-ocpucv-TwGCmLfPd3U9hQ][sentences][4]: SearchParseException[[sentences][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"appalto\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"terms\":{\"regulations.regulation_name\":\"Cod. civ.\"}}]}},\"facets\":{\"authorities\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"authority_detail_2\",\"size\":10,\"all_terms\":false}},\"regulations\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"regulations.regulation_name\",\"size\":10,\"all_terms\":false}}},\"size\":5,\"from\":0}]]]; nested: }{[-ocpucv-TwGCmLfPd3U9hQ][sentences][0]: SearchParseException[[sentences][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"appalto\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"terms\":{\"regulations.regulation_name\":\"Cod. civ.\"}}]}},\"facets\":{\"authorities\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"authority_detail_2\",\"size\":10,\"all_terms\":false}},\"regulations\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"regulations.regulation_name\",\"size\":10,\"all_terms\":false}}},\"size\":5,\"from\":0}]]]; nested: }{[-ocpucv-TwGCmLfPd3U9hQ][sentences][1]: SearchParseException[[sentences][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"appalto\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},{\"terms\":{\"regulations.regulation_name\":\"Cod. civ.\"}}]}},\"facets\":{\"authorities\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"authority_detail_2\",\"size\":10,\"all_terms\":false}},\"regulations\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"regulations.regulation_name\",\"size\":10,\"all_terms\":false}}},\"size\":5,\"from\":0}]]]; nested: }]",
"status": 500
```

}

And here JSON error parsed to more 'humar readable form':

```
SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[-ocpucv-TwGCmLfPd3U9hQ][sentences][4]: SearchParseException[[sentences][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
[{"query":
   {"bool":
     {"must": [
       {"query_string":{"query":"appalto","default_operator":"AND"}},
       {"terms":{"regulations.regulation_name":"Cod. civ."}}
     ]}
   },
    "facets":
     {"authorities":
       {"terms":
         {"field":"authority_detail_2","size":10,"all_terms":false}
       },
      "regulations":
       {"terms":
         {"field":"regulations.regulation_name","size":10,"all_terms":false}
       }
     },
     "size":5,"from":0}]
]];
nested: }{[-ocpucv-TwGCmLfPd3U9hQ][sentences][0]: SearchParseException[[sentences][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"appalto","default_operator":"AND"}},{"terms":{"regulations.regulation_name":"Cod. civ."}}]}},"facets":{"authorities":{"terms":{"field":"authority_detail_2","size":10,"all_terms":false}},"regulations":{"terms":{"field":"regulations.regulation_name","size":10,"all_terms":false}}},"size":5,"from":0}]]];
nested: }{[-ocpucv-TwGCmLfPd3U9hQ][sentences][1]: SearchParseException[[sentences][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"appalto","default_operator":"AND"}},{"terms":{"regulations.regulation_name":"Cod. civ."}}]}},"facets":{"authorities":{"terms":{"field":"authority_detail_2","size":10,"all_terms":false}},"regulations":{"terms":{"field":"regulations.regulation_name","size":10,"all_terms":false}}},"size":5,"from":0}]]];
nested: }]
```

Any idea how to implement correctly has_many association in Tire?

**PS** And YES I have run rake task after changing Tire mapping.

---

***EDIT:***

OK. I fixed `500` error by changing one line in code (terms => term).

```
  must { term 'regulations.regulation_name', params[:regulation_name] } if params[:regulation_name].present?
```

But now my search results are empty? Anyone know how to fix this?
Perhaps I should use other kind of match (I am currently using `boolean` + `must` combo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a typo. When I fixed this everything works fine.

I will post clear code for other users

-mappings

```
  mapping do
    indexes :id
    indexes :authority_name, :type => :string, :index => "not_analyzed"
    indexes :authority_detail_1, :type => :string, :index => "not_analyzed"
    indexes :authority_detail_2, :type => :string, :index => "not_analyzed"

    indexes :regulations do
      indexes :name, :type => :string, :index => "not_analyzed"
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(:include => [:rules, :regulations, :speaker])
  end
```

-search method

```
  def self.search(params)
    empty_params = false
    if params[:query].blank? && params[:authority_name].blank? &&
      params[:authority_detail_1].blank? && params[:authority_detail_2].blank? &&
      params[:regulation_name].blank? && params[:regulation_number].blank? &&
      params[:regulation_year].blank? && params[:regulation_article].blank?
      empty_params = true
    end

    unless empty_params
      tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 5, load: true) do
        query do
          boolean do
            must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
            must { term :authority_name, params[:authority_name] } if params[:authority_name].present?
            must { term :authority_detail_1, params[:authority_detail_1] } if params[:authority_detail_1].present?
            must { term :authority_detail_2, params[:authority_detail_2] } if params[:authority_detail_2].present?

            must { term "regulations.name", params[:regulation_name] } if params[:regulation_name].present?
            must { term "regulations.norm_number", params[:regulation_number] } if params[:regulation_number].present?
            must { term "regulations.year", params[:regulation_year] } if params[:regulation_year].present?
            must { term "regulations.article_number", params[:regulation_article] } if params[:regulation_article].present?
          end
        end
        # raise to_curl
      end
    else
      tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 5, load: true) do
        query do
          all
        end
      end
    end
  end
```